# I want to protect type as const with other type on typescript

Tags: typescript

Please let me know if there is a more suitable title.

For example, I add C in type AB. I hope typecheck error in ABSentences.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/ja/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAQQCE4BeOAb1Li-oH4AuOCgB2lTtwb9BI0gF9yaCEIDO8RgGUkQmJrRIlAtnADaAaySU4wIXDOUImREgCOAV2BEAJgB5GAPgC6AipQVgDmcDIs7GJcdAL4MAAWwEqWqXQAdPgANDFwDPFJKWn5WbmRKKkKyjCkQA)

## Example code

```
type AB = {
    A?: any
    B?: any
}

const ABSentences: { [key in keyof Required<AB>]: string } = {
    A: 'this is A.',
    B: 'this is B.',
} as const
```

I want to use `type AB` to protect key of `ABSentences` .

Do you have any good ideas?

## actual typeof ABSentences

```
const ABSentences: {
    A: string;
    B: string;
}
```

## expect typeof ABSentences

```
const ABSentences: {
    A: 'this is A.';
    B: 'this is B.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ABSentences = {
    A: 'this is A.',
    B: 'this is B.',
} as const
```

Just remove explicit type annotation if you are using `as const`

Comment: For example, I add C in type AB. I hope typecheck error in ABSentences.